# Fetch data using SQL

Tags: php, sql

```
function getadminByadminemail($admin_email){
        global $conn;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin_email = '".$admin_email."' ";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query) <= 0){
            return false;
        } else {
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            return $data;
        }
}
```

Before, I have been using this code and this code works without any error..
But recently, if doesn't fetch any data from the database...

Comment: Any error messages? What have you done to debug?

Comment: echo the query and try running it in db

Comment: How are you verifying that it "doesn't fetch any data"?

Comment: no error message

Comment: The return value is false i.e. 0

Comment: in db it fetch data

Comment: "The return value is false"  Okay, but how _specifically_ are you checking/verifying this?  Nothing in the given code produces an output, so are you checking the return value somewhere else and doing an output there? If so, you should show that code too.  Are you doing an output in the code above but just not showing it?  If so, you should update the code to reflect that.

Comment: There is also a possible SQL-Injection pleas sanitize your inputs. Have you maybe stored the email with uper or lower case ? you are comparing strings direct so they should be equal.